# how to make UI like Mi Store?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

*I want to make UI ilke Mi Store, in that by default status bar and action bar is transparent and after scrolling it will get white background.*

```
getWindow().setFlags(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

*After using this it will make status bar transparent but some mobile having home button on screen so those buttons also get transparent how to avoid it*[image]

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is modify theme that you are using

values/styles.xml

```
    <resources>
        <style name="Theme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
            <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/white</item>
        </style>
    </resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme">
        ...
    </activity>
```